# Tomcat process is getting aborted/killed after Ansible finishes

Tags: tomcat, ansible

I'm using Ansible `2.8.4-1.el7` in order to automate some tasks against a series of RedHat instances/servers.

I'm logging into the instances via SSH (using a "passwordless" key) with a user that **can run processes** as `tomcat`, but **it cannot** `sudo` as such completely. Tomcat servers have a script with some functions in order to control the `start` and `stop` actions...and that's what I want to mimic with Ansible, but so far, whenever I do: `/some/path/tomcat9_dev/bin/tomcat9_dev start` it does start the server, but the process exits after Ansible finishes the execution.

Is there a way to actually execute that script and leave the Tomcat server running after Ansible finishes?

> If I login to the server(s) via SSH, execute the script and exit, it works perfectly fine. I also put a sleep time to the start script,  executed it via Ansible and can see the Tomcat process, test the Web application(s), etc., but again, after Ansible finishes, the process exits.

---

I did start using the `service` module like this:

```
- name: Stop service
  systemd:
    state: stopped
    name: tomcat9_dev

- name: Start service
  systemd:
    enabled: yes
    state: started
    name: tomcat9_dev
```

...but that doesn't do anything, it **always** times out when starting the server (though it doesn't timeout when stopping it, but that actually doesn't stop it either...I've run this alone several times with the server up and running). The `/some/path/tomcat9_dev/bin/tomcat9_dev.service` file looks like:

```
[Unit]
Description=Apache Tomcat Web Application Container
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking

Environment=JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64
Environment=CATALINA_PID=/some/path/tomcat9_dev/temp/tomcat.pid
Environment=CATALINA_HOME=/some/path/tomcat9_dev
Environment=CATALINA_BASE=/some/path/tomcat9_dev
Environment='CATALINA_OPTS=-Xms512M -Xmx1024M -server -XX:+UseParallelGC'
Environment='JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom'
ExecStart=/some/path/tomcat9_dev/bin/tomcat9_dev start
ExecStop=/some/path/tomcat9_dev/bin/tomcat9_dev stop

User=tomcat
Group=tomcat
UMask=0007
RestartSec=10
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

> I'm not entirely sure if starting Tomcat via the script might interfere with Ansible and the `service` module.

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to run either the `service` wrapper or `systemctl` directly to start and stop that service unit by hand on the system that you're trying to command/control with Ansible? Because that would be step 1.

What is `/some/path/tomcat9_dev/bin/tomcat9_dev.service`? because that's important in terms of systemd and did you do a `daemon-reload` after installing that unit file?

Also, the script that resides at `/some/path/tomcat9_dev/bin/tomcat9_dev` does it leave tomcat running in the foreground or the background? Again, because that's important to systemd.

Comment: Those are great pointers to me! I didn't have any idea where to start with this...thanks! So I'm unable to run the service, it asks me for some password in order to "manage system services or units"; that's more likely the reason why Ansible timeouts. `/some/path/tomcat9_dev/bin/tomcat9_dev.service` is an **exact copy** of what you would find in `/etc/systemd/system/tomcat9_dev.service`, and yes, it's installed and reloaded. I'm not entirely sure about the foreground/background part; it's execute like: `/some/path/tomcat9_dev/bin/tomcat9_dev_catalina.sh start &>/dev/null`